# fql & fbconnect for iphone - find out logged in user's profile start date

Tags: iphone, facebook

I need to know when a users's profile was created. Is this possible through fql?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such field available.

Comment: Ok I'll take your word for it

Comment: @Mike: you can see that yourself in `users.getInfo` (rest) and in `/me` (graph).

Comment: Well I simply need to find out when the first 'stream' record (wallpost or status update) was made on their wall. So I'm trying 
SELECT post_id,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = <uid> ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 1 but it doesn't give me the first post :(... it gives me my latest one